# Откат промежуточного коммита

Tags: git

Есть 5 коммитов. Изменения в 3 коммите были ошибочными. Как откатить изменения так, чтобы сохранился прогресс 1, 2, 4, 5 коммитов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно откатить изменения сделанные в 3-ем коммите:
`git revert commit3-SHA`

Comment: Точно! Проверил. Работает как надо. Спасибо.

Comment: @JerryGreen, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, примите его(галочка рядом с ответом)

Answer (score 1):

Либо, только если изменения не залиты на удаленный репозиторий

```
git rebase -i <commit2-sha>
```

и там удалить строку с третьим коммитом, оставив только 4 и 5.

Оба способа (`rebase -i` и `revert`) подходят, если в коммитах изменялись разные файлы.  Если файл изменился в третьем, а потом в 4 и/или 5, то придется доработать вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Я в таких случаях делаю rebase с параметрами force, interactive на коммит 2 и исключаю коммит 3.

Но если коммит уже отправлен в удаленный репозиторий то лучше как советует ixSci